# How do I get rid of the ^I symbols in vim?

Tags: vim

Here is a screen shot of some code in Vim.  Those `^I` symbols annoy me.  If they are tabs, why doesn't Vim just display them as whitespace as expected?  I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

```
:set list
```

command causes `vi` or `vim` to display tab characters as `^I` and end-of-line as `$`.

Type:

```
:set nolist
```

to turn it off. (It should be off by default unless you've set in your `.vimrc`.)

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html#05.7

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know why someone might want `:set list` on?  It turns out it is on in my `.vimrc`.

Comment: @JonCrowell: I sometimes turn it on temporarily if I need to see whether some whitespace is tabs or spaces (it matters for `Makefile`s, for example).

Comment: @JonCrowell I normally end up using it to find out where the end of line is (although there are other ways to find it).

Comment: The appearance of the invisible characters made visible by set list can be customized to good effect with the listchar option. See :help 'listchar'. Also, why do you have that option in your vimrc if you don't know what it does and don't even know it's there?